# Information not available, symbols not loaded for msxml3.dll in vc2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to create an instance by this

```
docPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30));
```

but result is

```
Information not available, symbols not loaded for msxml3.dll
```

Please help me in this case. In starting of my project, I'm using

```
#import "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\msxml3.dll" 

**#define __USE_MSXML2_NAMESPACE__**

**using namespace MSXML2;**
```

After doing this dll is not loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant  Hello sir, All symbols successfully loaded but after this i got same result "Information not available, symbols not loaded for msxml3.dll"  at time of createinstance. Please help in this case why symbols not loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant {0x04524578 <No type information available in symbol file for msxml3.dll>} this type of error comes